# Prove that the function $f(x,y)=|y|\sin(x)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For the proof, I calculated the partial derivatives of $f$, which are both $0$:
$f'_x=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}{\frac{f(0+\Delta x, 0)-f(0,0)}{\Delta x}}=0$. Analogically for $f'_y$.
Then, this means that $f$ is differentiable $\iff\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{|y|\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}=0$. Obviously, whichever direction I use for the limit ($y=x$ and $x\to0$ or $x\to0$ and $y=0$, etc), it is always zero. Do I have to prove explicitly that $\lim\limits_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{|y|\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}=0$, for example like this: 
$0\leq|\frac{|y|\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x^+y^2}}|\leq|\frac{|y||x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|=|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq\sqrt{\frac{|xy|}{2}}\to0$

 or it's enough to show that the limit is zero in just one direction? If I need to prove explicitly that the limit is zero, then is the method above the preferred way, or I should use the definition for limit of a multivariable function?

Comment: You should prove that the limit is 0. It's easy to construct example for a limit to exist in one  direction but doesn't exist in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ sense.

Comment: What is the last inequality in your “proof”?

Comment: @TedShifrin The squeeze lemma (the squeeze theorem). Because both the lower and upper bounds are the same, then this means that the expression between those bounds approaches infinity, as $x\to0$ and $y\to0$. Is it wrong? If you'r asking about the very last inequality, not the whole logic chain, it should be true, as it comes from the formula $(a-b)^2>=0$

Comment: I'm asking how you got $\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le \sqrt{\frac{|xy|}2}$. It's far easier to observe that $\frac{|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le 1$, and so your quantity is bounded by $|x|$. I take the squeeze lemma for granted.